# T-SQL for "Not quite a Pivot"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following source data (the data is an extract for a source of several hundred rows.):

```
ID  CodeID  Code
3749    69  354
3750    69  864
33721  130  XXX
33722  130  319
30446  159  XXX
30447  159  XXX
```

and using T-SQL I need to achieve:

```
CodeID  Code1   Code2
69      354     864
130     XXX     319
159     XXX     XXX
```

This doesn't seem to fit the structure for a pivot table and I have no idea how to achieve this. Does anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: Should 864 be in the 130 row? Should it not be 319?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a `pivot` if you first assign each of the values a number using `row_number()`

```
select codeid, [1] as Code1,[2] as Code2 -- .... ,[3] etc
from
( 
    select codeid, code, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by codeid order by id) rn
    from yourtable
) p
pivot (max(code) for rn in ([1],[2])) p2 --, [3]... etc
```